# In rails is it possible to load class layout dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need message to have a different layout in project, is it possible in rails to do something like this?

```
Class Messages::New < @project? ProjectLayout : NormalLayout
end  #i treid this, don't work, since @project has not been initiated.
```

thanks

Answer (score 22):

this may help you

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout :get_layout

  def get_layout
    @project? ? 'ProjectLayout' : 'NormalLayout'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, since the question is unclear, you can also set layout for only one action with the render option.

```
render :action => 'new', :layout => 'layoutname'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply layouts at the Controller level:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout :project
end
```

[Layout method documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout) has an example on how to do conditional layouts

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply the rails layouts at `controller` level and individual `action` levels.

**Unique layout in for each controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin"

  def index
   # logic 
  end
end
```

** The above line `layout "admin"` will load the admin layout each time the message controller gets invoked. For that, you must have a layout created in your `layouts/admin.html.rb` file.**

**Dynamic layout for each controller**

```
 class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   layout :dynamic_layout

   def index
    # logic 
   end

 protected
 def dynamic_layout
   if current_user.admin?
      "admin"       # Show admin layout
   else
     "other_layout"   # Show other_layout
    end
   end   
 end
```

**# Individual Action Level Layouts**
If you want to display different layouts for each action you can do that.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout :dynamic_layout

  def index
   # logic 
   render :action => 'index', :layout => 'index_layout'
  end

  def show
   # logic
   render :action => 'show', :layout => 'show_layout'
  end   
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Decide the layout in the controller rather then the model. Your ProjectsController can use it's own ProjectLayout and MessagesController can then use the normal layout if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents in ApplicationController:

```
before_action :layout_by_action

@@actions = %w(new edit create update index)

def layout_by_action
  if @@actions.include? params[:action]
    self.class.layout 'admin'
  else
    self.class.layout 'application'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html):

```
layout -> {
    if something?
      'my-layout'
    else
      'my-other-layout'
    end
  }
```